# Non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'unsigned long' to 'int' in initializer list

Tags: c++

please help a c++ newbie understand what is going wrong here. I got compile error message of `Non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'unsigned long' to 'int' in initializer list` on leetcode web and my local ubuntu terminal, but it works perfectly fine on my CLion IDE.   Also could explain why I got the error and how to solve it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> heights({{1, 2, 2, 3, 5}, {3, 2, 3, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 3, 1}, {6, 7, 1, 4, 5}, {5, 1, 1, 2, 4}});
    deque<vector<int>> dq;

    for (int i=0;i<heights.size();i++){
        dq.push_back({i,heights[0].size()-1});
    }


    for (auto vec: dq){
        if (vec.empty())
            cout<< "vec is empty";
        else
            cout<<vec[0]<< " "<< vec[1]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Soon as switch to `pair` from `vector<int>`, the error is gone. It's quite confusing to a newbie like me. Please shed some light on this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> heights({{1, 2, 2, 3, 5}, {3, 2, 3, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 3, 1}, {6, 7, 1, 4, 5}, {5, 1, 1, 2, 4}});
    deque<pair<int, int>> dq;

    for (int i=0;i<heights.size();i++){
        dq.push_back({i,heights[0].size()-1});
    }


    for (auto [u,v]: dq){
        cout<<u<< " "<< v<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For those who want to close this question, I can delete/close it, but could you please give any help.

Comment: Unrelated: `#include <iostream>` and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in the same file suggests you don't know what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` does and how it should be used. [Here's some reading to help you out with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: If you are compiling with GCC, add the `-pedantic-errors` flag to the compiler invocation and it will produce the same error. Without that flag GCC will treat it as just a warning (which I think it should have given you).

Comment: Unrelated: `heights[0].size()-1` will turn into a very large number if `heights[0]` is empty. `size` returns an unsigned integer and 0-1 in unsigned arithmetic will roll around to the maximum possible value rather than provide -1.

Comment: @user4581301 In this case since the very large number is converted into a signed integer of a smaller rank (equal rank would also work), it will convert to -1 (guaranteed by standard since C++20; reliable assumption on 2's complement systems before that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use brace-initialization, it is forbidden for a *narrowing conversion* to be used to convert from the type of the value in the braced list to the type that the constructor actually requires. `heights[0].size()-1` has type `size_t`, and the constructor of `std::vector<int>` takes `std::initializer_list<int>`. Usually, `int` cannot represent all values of type `size_t`, which means that `size_t` to `int` is a narrowing conversion. You can fix this using an explicit cast:

```
dq.push_back({i,static_cast<int>(heights[0].size()-1)});
```

When the type being constructed is `std::pair<int, int>`, it is a different story. No conversion actually occurs when calling the constructor; instead, the following constructor is called:

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );
```

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

Internally, presumably in the constructor initializer list, the constructor will convert `size_t` to `int`, but this will not be done inside braces, so it's legal.

Answer (score 2):

C++ language doesn't allow narrowing implicit conversions within a braced initialiser list (unless the value compile time constant). This protects you from making certain obvious mistakes.

This is the braced initialiser list: `{i,heights[0].size()-1}`.

A narrowing conversion is a conversion into a type that cannot represent all values of the source type. The type of the expression `heights[0].size()-1` was on your system `unsigned long` which on your system can represent values that  the `int` type cannot represent.

You can fix the issue by doing an explicit conversion. It is safe in this case because we know that the size is non-zero, and doesn't exceed the maximum value representable by `int`:

```
static_cast<int>(heights[0].size()-1)
```